# "vagrant up" problem with virtualbox

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, vagrant

```
$ vagrant up

The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'scdev' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.
```

Then I tried to investigate and seems like I already have those packages:

```
$ VBoxManage --version
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
 Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
 headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

 You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.0.24_Ubuntur108355

$ sudo apt install linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0.59.62).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
virtualbox-dkms is already the newest version (5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just a few months old, but I run into this problem occasionally and I wanted to post the solution/cause for my vagrant doing this.

The problem (for me) is generally caused by Vagrant unexpectedly ending (read my laptop battery dying). Here are a list of things that have worked for me:

1. Generally a `modprobe vboxdrv` will do the trick. This reapplies the kernel module, and everything is great.
2. Alternatively, reconfigure the package `dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-*`
3. Worst case, blow it all away and try again `sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-dkms linux-headers-generic; #etc`

Comment: 3rd option worked for me but without -dkms and linux-headers-generic... Only by simply upgrading to latest version of VirtualBox

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue. Any time certain core kernel updates are applied, my virtualbox won't start complaining (in red):

```
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.
```

I have tried reconfiguring. I have tried completely removing and re-installing both virtualbox and dkms support.  I can fix it by re-installing dkms any time it happens, but the next time the kernel gets an update, it pops up the red again and I have to go through it all over again.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps it solved for me

1. Boot your device and then disable the secure boot
2. Then run

   ```
   sudo apt-get install virtualbox
   ```

   in your terminal

...I think this will solve your problem

Comment: Rebooting didn't work for me but this solution did

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling Virtualization and disabling secure boot.This can be done by entering your computer's boot settings. Additionally install the linux-headers-generic and virtualbox-dkms if it asks for it.